# What character for EOF and end program?

Tags: c

I am currently reading The C Programming Language (1st ed). In section 1.5, under File Copying, the books introduces the concept of EOF.

```
#define EOF -1

main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

When I run the program above, the program takes an input and prints the input out again.

```
omfg
omfg
how
how
do 
do 
i end 
i end 
this?
this?
-1
-1
```

I was thinking that typing `-1` would end the program because EOF is `-1`. But as you see, it still doesn't end. Is that because EOF's -1 is int, while the -1 I enter is char? I am not sure.

So how do I actually use EOF?

Thanks.

Comment: To the close voter: I/O is at the boundary of programming and computer usage. To someone new to programming, that boundary is hard to see, and helping a new programmer get better is entirely within the mission of SO, IMHO.

Comment: Do be aware that K&R 1st edition is rather elderly. As you move through the book, you will rapidly run into things that were true about the C language when the book was written that are no longer true, or which were refined and "clarified" by the C standards committee. That said, it is still one of the best language references written, and there are later editions that bring it up to date with the standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOF` is not a character; rather it is a condition on a stream. So that code that processes an input stream a character at a time can easily detect the end of file condition, the function `getchar()` is defined to return an `int` not `char`, and to return the signal value `EOF` when the end of the input is detected.

At the terminal in Unix systems, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to cause `stdin` to report that the end of file has been reached, which causes `getchar()` to return `EOF`. On Windows at the command prompt, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to get the same effect. These characters are interpreted by the OS (in the input device driver) to allow for the `EOF` condition to be typed manually.

When your program is reading from a file instead of a terminal, the `EOF` condition will arise naturally after the last character of the file is read. In Unix, you can read any characters at all from the file, including a Ctrl+D character, without triggering an end of file condition because reading from a file does not involve a tty device driver that would do that translation.

Similarly, when piping the output of one program to a second, the second will see EOF when the first closes its output stream, and not see EOF just because a Ctrl+D was in the data.

Note that under Windows, with some C compilers and files in "text" mode, reading a Ctrl+Z character can cause a premature end of file condition. This is for historical reasons: Windows borrows a lot of behavior from DOS, and DOS from CP/M-80. In CP/M-80, the file system only knew the size of a file in units of "blocks" (512 bytes per block). In order for a text file to end cleanly, the Ctrl+Z character was chosen as unlikely to be a valid part of a document and used to signal the end of the text file. The end of a file on disk would be a block that contained at least one Ctrl+Z character in it somewhere, and often contained random additional data that just happened to still be in memory after that Ctrl+Z.

Comment: ^d does not "cause stdin to read an EOF"; it closes the stream.  When  the stream is closed, getchar returns EOF.  EOF is *not* read from the stream; it is merely a value that is returned by getchar to indicate that the stream has either closed or encountered a read error.

Comment: No, it causes the terminal driver to signal end of file on the next call to `read(2)`. The Ctrl+D is handled by the terminal driver itself as long as the terminal is not set to too raw an input mode. It is true that the EOF is not formally *read* from the stream. It is a condition that causes calls to `read(2)` to return what it has and report the EOF condition up the stack. The streams implemented by stdio get set to an EOF condition, which `getchar()` reports to its caller by returning the special value `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

Press the `Ctrl-D` key combination.

Comment: I know that I can end the program with Ctrl+C on mac. Sorry I wasn't clear. I am wondering if I can end it programatically

Comment: @dmtri.com Ctrl-D was not a typo, it produces an end of input - the program continues but receives an “end of file” when reading from stdin. Ctrl-C interrupts the program, it is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

You need to produce an actual end of file, not type in `-1`. `-1` is not an end of file, it is two characters: `'-'`, and `'1'`. Meanwhile end of file is not any character, but a condition. (As an analogy: the road ending is a condition, a sign on the road saying “road ends” is not.)

On many systems you can produce and end of file when typing the input manually by pressing ctrl-D (ctrl-Z on Windows/DOS). Or if you pipe the input from a file (`./myprogram <file.txt`) then the end of the file results in an end of file condition.